# Multinomial Logistic Regreesion with Lasso penalty in R

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, regression-coefficients, lasso, multinomial-distribution

I am applying regularized logistic regression (in R) to the handwritten
digits data set. I have fitted a logistic multinomial model with lasso penalty to the training data. I am asked to obtain the coefficients for the best lasso fit for **each class** and plot the respective images that have a black point at a pixel if this pixel is used as predictor in this class, and a white point if this pixel is not used. I also have to interpret these images.

**Data:**

There are 257 columns (1 output column. and 256 columns for 256 pixels of a 16x16 matrix representing a digit). There are more than 7000 observations.

A sample of the data looks like this:

```
 [![train\[1:5\]
     V1     V2     V3     V4     V5
1     6 -1.000 -1.000 -1.000 -1.000
2     5 -1.000 -1.000 -1.000 -0.813
3     4 -1.000 -1.000 -1.000 -1.000][1]][1]
```

I am using the following functions:

```
lasso.mod<- glmnet(x,y, family = "multinomial",alpha=1, lambda=grid, standardize = TRUE)
cv.lasso<-cv.glmnet(x,y,alpha=1, nfold=5)

tmp_coeffs <- coef(cv.lasso, s = "lambda.1se"
data.frame(name = tmp_coeffs@Dimnames[[1]][tmp_coeffs@i + 1], coefficient = tmp_coeffs@x)
```

But I only get coefficients for one class ( I think)

this is the output I get:

```
name   coefficient

1     (Intercept)  1.8636242914

2              V2 -1.1965085609

3              V8 -0.0404422986

4              V9 -0.4736484517

5             V10  0.0146219236

.
.
.
```

Can anyone please help me obtain the coefficients for the best lasso fit for each class and plot the respective images that have a black point at a pixel if this pixel is used as predictor in this class, and a white point if this pixel is not used?

Thanks in advance!